# Different random seeds lead to big classifier performance difference

Tags: machine-learning

I've a dataset for binary classification. I tried various algorithms using Weka. Then I noticed that if I change the seed of the random number generator I get different classification accuracy results. For example in one run I get 65% and in another run I get 72% accuracy. In all runs I use 10-fold cross validation. Is this variation in accuracy results normal? Or any idea on what might be the cause of the variation?
Thanks

Comment: That's called a problem of instability. Does it happen with all algorithms? It usually only happens with specific algorithms on specific datasets (small n). I you do repeated CV (weka should do it per default), you should get confidence intervals for your performance metric. Is this 65 to 72 difference within what can be expected in light of the confidence interval?

Comment: @user7019377 I will check these and report back, thanks.

Comment: How small is your dataset?